# postgresql bdr error on starting cluster / service

Tags: postgresql, replication, database-replication

I'm trying to get postgresql 9.4 and BDR working.  Following this tutorial: 
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BDR_Quick_Start

Actually, my sysadmin provided me with a package to test with.  He's taken care of the compilation "stuff".

I have two instances running, one on port 5598 and the other on 5599. 
What I'm noticing is that when I leave the following line in the postgresql.conf file, I can't start the service:

```
 # Load BDR
 shared_preload_libraries = 'bdr'
```

the error message i get is:

```
FATAL:  could not access file "bdr": No such file or directory
```

When I remove the above line, it I can start the service on the specific port needed.
According to the BDR docs, if you get that message, you're missing the bdr 
contrib package:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BDR_Reference#Could_not_access_file_.22bdr.22:_No_such_file_or_directory

But I have it installed.  I just don't know how to verify it because I don't exactly know what it does.

When i check my package manager to see everything that's been installed, I have the following items listed:

```
postgresql-bdr
postgresql-bdr-contrib
postgresql-bdr-dbg
```

My apologies in advance for being such a noob.  But i'm not a sysadmin, linux is relatively new to me... and it looks like BDR is pretty new too.
I'm just trying to collect as much information as possible for my sysadmins to be able to fix whatever is wrong with this package...

Thanks.

Comment: I believe this is a result of not updating the path. Run after every restart or add it to your ~/.bash_profile:
Debian:
`export PATH=$HOME/2ndquadrant_bdr/bdr/bin:$PATH`

CentOS/Fedora:
`export PATH=/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin:$PATH`

Comment: Please note that the documentation that you are referencing is outdated. The new valid documentation for BDR is located at bdr-project.org/docs/stable/index.html @QAAutomator if you follow that documentation there is $HOME/2ndquadrant_bdr/bdr/bin only exists if you install the temporary patched method to test BDR http://bdr-project.org/docs/0.9.0/quickstart-installing.html . I have the same problem, if I find a solution I will be back.